# Community Studio 2017 Lagging with long fortran code

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, lag

I have a main.for and a modules.for (I can't share either of them).

Main.for contains 500+ lines of code and modules.for contains 13000+ lines of code. When I edit main.for, Community studio runs just fine but when I edit modules.for I have about 2 seconds to type anything before Community studio "freezes." The reason I put "freeze" in quotations is that it is not unresponsive as in I can still type and when Community studio recovers the typed letters during "freezing" would appear, and then Community studio enters another round of freezing because I typed something new.

I received the codes from my colleagues and they said they do not experience the same problem. However, they are using Community Studio 2015, 2013, or even earlier versions. My computer shouldn't be the problem either as I have 32 GB memory, Radeon R7 M465X, and usual setups in a new Optiplex 7450 AIO computer.

So I think it maybe related to the 2017 version of Community Studio, does anyone have an insight on this problem?

Comment: What kind of compiler do you use? How is it integrated into the visual studio?

Comment: Anyway, this will probably be best resolved by creating an as-small-as-possible [mcve] and reporting a bug to the vendor of your IDE.

Comment: `modules.for contains 13000+ lines of code` there's your problem. Break it up. 13K lines of code in a single file is a *very bad idea*. How are you going to find anything in such a large file?

Comment: @VladimirF I use the intel fortran compiler. It is integrated through the visual studio command scripts I found online. I have to see if I can create a as-small-as-possible example that can still proc the problem.... Thanks anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For sure I thought that having 13000 lines is a problem and I honestly don't like it either. But it is a legacy code and there are many things that work together and it will take some time to break them apart. However, this does not explain why my colleagues don't experience this problem

Comment: Do your colleagues have the saame scripts you found online?  If it is pre-Fortran90 Fortran you can safely move anything you want to different files. There is no dependence on things being in the same file in old Fortran.

Comment: @JesseFeng are you sure they don't? Most likely the grew accustomed to waiting. Or they disabled Intellisense and just use Visual Studio as a glorified Notepad or VS Code. Perhaps they use older compilers that *don't* perform online analysis and don't provide Intellisense? 13K rows is itself a *far* more serious problem that the delays. It's unmaintainalbe, untestable, unverifiable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am sure they don't as they know what I am talking about. What I found out is that the old versions don't have graphics acceleration. I turned it off and I no longer experience the lag.

Comment: @VladimirF I have found the solution see above comment. I just wanted to comment that I actually can't break the code into parts because one important umat subroutine that is used by a simulation program called Abaqus cannot include files (or something of that regard)

Comment: @JesseFeng on the contrary, it *is* due to the source code. Visual Studio uses WPF to display annotations, notifications etc. At 13K lines you get slow performance no matter the language. The solution is to *not* use 13K rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, sometimes graphics acceleration can cause problems like this. I turned off the option in Tools -> Options -> General -> Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience..." -> Uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available"